# Python if condition to continue parsing

Tags: python

This is my python script:

```
mock_data = ((23020, "in0"),
             (23000, "in1"),
             (23020, "in2"),
             (0, "in3"),
             (23060, "in4"),
             (23080, "in5"),
             (23100, "in6"),
             (0, "in7"))
mock_len = len(mock_data)
epsilon = 20
max_data = 0
isInInterval = True
for i in range(mock_len - 1):
    if isInInterval == True:
        if mock_data[i+1][0]-mock_data[i][0] == 20:
            max_data = mock_data[i+1][0]
            isInInterval = False
            print max_data
    if max_data != 0 and mock_data[i][0]==0:
        isInInterval = True
```

output:

```
23020
23080
```

But when i change the data to :

```
mock_data = ((23020, "in0"),
             (23000, "in1"),
             (23020, "in2"),
             (0, "in3"),
             (23060, "in4"),
             (23080, "in5"),
             (23100, "in6"),
             (10, "in7"),
             (100,"int8"),
             (1000,"int9"),
             (1020,"int10"),
             (300,"int11"))
```

The output with my current code will still be the same as above, but I also want to print 1020:

```
23020
23080
1020
```

What is best change in my code to also cover that case, cause at the moment my flags will only get true when I start from 0.

Comment: It is unclear what it is that you are trying to achieve. Are you simply trying to identify the start of a new data set, within the data, where originally you thought it would always start with zero but have now discovered that the start of a new sequence could be 0,10,300 or whatever. If so, as long as the start of a new sequence is always less than the previous value, then perhaps a test of `mock_data[i][0] < mock_data[i - 1][0]` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Look for example if I will make it like this :

```js
mock_data = ((23020, "in0"),
             (23000, "in1"),
             (23020, "in2"),
             (0, "in3"),
             (23060, "in4"),
             (23080, "in5"),
             (23100, "in6"),
             (10, "in7"),
             (100,"int8"),
             (1000,"int9"),
             (1020,"int10"),
             (300,"int11"))
mock_len = len(mock_data)
epsilon = 20
max_data = 0
isInInterval = True
for i in range(mock_len - 1):
    if isInInterval == True:
        if mock_data[i+1][0]-mock_data[i][0] == 20:
            max_data = mock_data[i+1][0]
            isInInterval = False
            print max_data
    if max_data != 0 and mock_data[i+1][0]>mock_data[i][0]+ 300:
        isInInterval = True
```

instead of **if max_data != 0 and mock_data[i][0]==0:** I did **if max_data != 0 and mock_data[i+1][0]>mock_data[i][0]+ 300:** but I dont this is best way to do it. Basically I want to change that flag, in a pythonic fashion in order to I don't have to reset my flag to True when I encounter 0.